# How do I increase the amount of store bought peanut butter from 1/2 cup to 1 cup in a peanut butter brownie recipe?

Tags: baking, brownies, ratio, peanut-butter

I have a chewy peanut butter brownie recipe that uses 1/2 cup JIF peanut butter. The recipe also includes 1/3 cup butter; 1 cup flour; & 2 eggs.

I want to increase the amount of peanut butter to 1 cup, so that I end up with a significantly higher percentage of peanut butter in the brownie, but the same amount of batter. What adjustments do I make to successfully increase the peanut butter to 1 cup? Since I am ONLY doubling the peanut butter how will the measurements of flour, butter, & eggs be affected?

I also have a fudgy brownie recipe that is my go to. Can I just match the measurements of the peanut butter brownie ingredients to the measurements of the fudgy brownie recipe with the exception of the amount of butter? The quantity of butter (I do use real butter), used in the fudgy brownie recipe is 1 1/4 cups. Would decreasing the amount of butter from 1 1/4 cup to 3/4 cup and adding 1/2 c of peanut butter work?

I want a chewy & fudgy peanut butter brownie.

Comment: Are you trying to make it a higher protein recipe? You might try warming the second 1/2 cup so that it’s runny enough to drizzle over the mix once it’s in the pan nut before baking. Swirling the drizzles with a skewer might give you thin veins of peanut butter through the brownies.

Comment: I don't know JIF peanut butter & how it may differ from any other. Google tells me it's an American product, apparently. Doubling any 'regular' peanut butter in that recipe would make mush, which may or may not set as it cools.

Comment: I want to thank you for answering my question. I did edit my question/post so that it is more specific. I have a fudgy brownie recipe that I am dedicated to & want the same texture in the peanut butter brownie recipe.

Comment: Recipes are create so that they work "as-is" for normal home cooks, if you change the proportions of the ingredients, you will change the recipe and change the intended result.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Knowing the reason will help us suggest substitutions that will best suit your goal.

Comment: I have a fudgy, chewy brownie recipe that I am dedicated to & want the same characteristics in the peanut butter brownie recipe I have. The fudgy brownie recipe has 1.1/4 sticks butter; 3/4 c. hershey's special dark chocolate cocoa powder; 1/2 tsp. vanilla extract; 3 large eggs; 1 tbsp. strong coffee; 1/2 c. all-purpose flour. This is the best incredibly ooey-gooey fudgy, chewy brownie I have eaten up to this point. in my life!  I want to adapt my peanut butter brownie recipe so I can have the  ooey-gooey, fudgy & chewy. character that my fudgy brownie has with an intense peanut butter flavor.

Comment: If the goal is simply 'more peanut butter', you could add swirls of peanut butter : https://www.pillsburybaking.com/recipes/peanut-butter-swirl-brownies-8799

Comment: @TexasGal if your goal is to make a peanut butter version of the brownies you like, then why are you specifically looking for recipes with one cup of peanut butter? I think you aren't asking the question you really have.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to substitute regular butter with any nut butter (like peanut butter), it will add a nutty flavour of course but this shouldn't be an issue since there's already peanut butter included. The difference is the fat content however, have a look at [this post](https://www.jessicagavin.com/substitutes-for-butter/#:%7E:text=Nuts%20like%20peanut%2C%20almond%2C%20cashew,before%20adding%20into%20a%20recipe.) that explains it quite well.

They mentioning adding oil to the peanut butter and mixing it to get a more butter-like effect. So you could add 1/2 cup of peanut butter (this is in addition to the 1/2 cup that's already included making it 1 cup of peanut butter total) with 1/2 cup of oil (I recommend coconut for best flavour with baking) and change the amount of butter to 1/4 cup (removing 1 cup as the substitute).

1 1/4 cup butter = 1/2 cup peanut butter + 1/2 cup oil + 1/4 cup of butter

This gets pretty complicated but is likely the most accurate. If you're open to experimenting a bit, I would honestly just try it without the oil and see how they come out, hopefully the difference in texture isn't noticeable enough.

Comment: I appreciate the link & the time you have taken to respond to my post. I want my peanut butter brownies to have the ooey-gooey chewy texture that my fudgy brownies have and I want the peanut butter brownies to have an intense peanut butter flavor. I am going to go back to the link and read it again. I inevitably missed something on the 1st time around. Sometimes, a 3 year old pays more attention to the details than I do. Lol.